# import git project,how to get standard java project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

i import j2ee-jms github

> https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples.git

,like this [image]
but jms-batch is not a java project,i add the .classpath and .project file to jms-batch but not effect.
how to convert these to standard java project?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the maven eclipse plugin (m2e) and import the project as a maven project. This worked for me.